# How to Export and Import Database from workbench SQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How can i export database from workbench and import to phpmyadmin using dump file. ?

Comment: @jarlh you edited what ?

Comment: Switched from <sql> to <mysql> tag, since this is a MySQL related issue.

Comment: No problem. With the correct tags questions get the best attention, and best answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### make sure you on root[image]

### Export Data syntax
mysqldump -u username -p database_name > data-dump.sql

### Import DB
mysql -u root -p purchase_commerce < /opt/data-dump.sql

Comment: Thanks working fine... @Darshan malani you such a good developer.